# ¿Como mover item hijo dentro de un contenedor con css grid?

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid-layout

Tengo la siguiente duda, como puedo mover un ítem hijo al principio de su contenedor?? ya coloqué justify-content: end en el contenedor y justify-self: start en el ítem hijo, adjunto código e imagen para los que me puedan ayudar, gracias!! Vengo de flexbox asi que igual no me ha costado aprender css grid, pero tiene mas diferencias que similitudes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
    margin: 50px auto;
    background-color: red;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px; 
    grid-template-rows: 50px;
    grid-gap: 15px;
    line-height: 50px;
    justify-content: end;
    
}

.item{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.item-1{
    justify-self: start;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#inicio" class="item item-1">Inicio</a>
    <div class="container">
        
        <a href="#noticia" class="item item-2">Noticias</a>
        <a href="#nosotros" class="item item-3">Nosotros</a>
        <a href="#contactenos" class="item item-4">Contactenos</a> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Considero que el paso prudente en este caso es manejarse a través de: *FlexBox* pues nos da libertad de decidir la distribución de los elementos sobre el eje en el cual se encuentren.

Pues con *CSS Grid* tienes opciones como:

- justify-self
- align-self

Pero estos te van a permitir decidir la distribución del elemento sobre la celda en la cual se encuentra inscrutado, **entonces en teoría** tendrías que acomodar cada uno de los elementos del menú en una celda de la rejilla.

En cambio con *FlexBox* podemos proceder de esta forma:

- Al contenedor principal le indicamos que sus elementos serán cajas flexibles
- Les damos a los elementos una distribución horizontal con separación entre ellos

Ahora para lograr la separación entre el primer elemento del menú con respecto de los 3 restantes aplicamos:

- Seleccionamos a uno de los elementos por medio de su clase `item` y por medio de la [pseudoclase **`nth-child`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) indicamos que empiece la selección del segundo de estos en específico
- Una vez hecho lo anterior le damos a dicho elemento (*el segundo*) un margen izquierdo de *X* cantidad de pixeles **para hacer notoria la separación del primer elementos del resto de ellos**

```html
    <style>
      .container {
        background-color: crimson;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
      .item {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .item:nth-child(2) {
        margin-left: 100px;
      }
    </style>
        <div class="container">
              <a href="#inicio" class="item item-1">Inicio</a>
              <a href="#noticia" class="item item-2">Noticias</a>
              <a href="#nosotros" class="item item-3">Nosotros</a>
              <a href="#contactenos" class="item item-4">Contactenos</a> 
        </div>
```

Con esta propuesta:

- Puedes dejar a todos los *item* dentro de un solo contenedor
- Evitas tener que usar un segundo contenedor interno para agrupar del 2do al 4to elemento
- tu maquetación en *flexbox* puede encajar perfecto y continuarla con un sistema de rejilla superior que tengas con *CSS Grid*

Comment: Una respuesta excelente! Una observación: puedes utilizar `.item:nth-child(2) {margin-left: auto;}` y en este caso necesitas un padding para los items.

Answer (score 1):

Si bien ya te respondieron con algo totalmente valido, es mas sencillo hacerlo aplicando un margen automático al primer child del flex

Probado en IE11 y superior, antes de eso no tengo idea

```css
#content{display: flex; justify-content: flex-end}
#content div{padding: 10px}
#content div:first-child{margin-right:auto}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div>demo</div>
  <div>demo</div>
  <div>demo</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizás no he entendido bien la pregunta, pero con CSS Grid puedes poner un item donde tu quieras dentro de la rejilla, solo tienes que manipular `grid-colum: [linea Inicial] / [linea final]`, tambien puedes hacer lo mismo con las **Rows**

```
          .item:nth-child(2) {
            grid-column: 1/2;
          }
```

Flexbox y Grid, se complementan. Con Grid puedes modificar la posición de las celdas, las áreas, las filas y las columnas con tan solo indicarle donde comienza y termina cada una de ellas

Answer (score 0):

Yo le asignaría 1 fracción al primer hijo y utilizaria un repeat para darle los 100px que quieres a los demás hijos, ya con el a:frist-of-type lo mueves a donde quieras.

```
   .container a:first-of-type{
        text-align: left;
       
    }
    
    .container{
        margin: 50px auto;
        background-color: red;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(3, 100px); 
        grid-template-rows: 50px;
        grid-gap: 15px;
        line-height: 50px;
        justify-content: end;
        padding: 0 20px;
        
    }
```